# terraform Invalid value for "seqs" parameter: all arguments must be lists or tuples; got string

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Why i'm not using the ID directly:

- I have multiple datalake's where the filesystem is deployed. It throws error "resource not found"  during the deployment.

What i'm trying to achieve now:

- i am trying to use concat function and create the ID's. which is throwing an error.

```
module.adlsfs["adlsfilesystem1"].time_sleep.wait_few_mins_fs: Refreshing state... [id=2022-07-23T21:45:55Z]
╷
│ Error: Invalid function argument
│ 
│   on ../../../tf-core-module/adls/fs/filesystem.tf line 20, in resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "storagedlsgen2fs":
│   20:   storage_account_id = concat("/subscriptions/",data.azurerm_subscription.current.id,"/resourceGroups/rsg-test/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/",each.value.staname)
│ 
│ Invalid value for "seqs" parameter: all arguments must be lists or tuples; got string.
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid function argument
│ 
│   on ../../../tf-core-module/adls/fs/filesystem.tf line 20, in resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "storagedlsgen2fs":
│   20:   storage_account_id = concat("/subscriptions/",data.azurerm_subscription.current.id,"/resourceGroups/rsg-test/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/",each.value.staname)
│ 
│ Invalid value for "seqs" parameter: all arguments must be lists or tuples; got string.
```

```
data "azurerm_subscription" "current" {
}

locals {
  staname = toset([
    for pair in sort(var.sta_name) : {
      staname  = pair
    }
  ])
}

//**********************************************************
//  Create File System in Datalake
//**********************************************************
resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "storagedlsgen2fs" {
  for_each = { for p in local.staname : jsonencode(p) => p }
  name               = var.adlsfilesystems
  storage_account_id = concat("/subscriptions/",data.azurerm_subscription.current.id,"/resourceGroups/resourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/",each.value.staname)
}
```

Is it even possible to use the function here? and how can i solve this.

thank you

Comment: What is the **full** error message, showing lines that produce error.

Comment: @Marcin thanks for reply. I have added the whole message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that instead of `concat`, you want `join`:

```
storage_account_id = join("",["/subscriptions/",data.azurerm_subscription.current.id,"/resourceGroups/resourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/",each.value.staname])
```